# How to re-program P1 and P1 buttons on Symbol WT41n0 on Windows CE5

Tags: vba, typescript, windows

We have Motorola/ Symbol WT41n0 with Windows Mobile CE5, and we were curious is it possible to make P1 and P2 buttons as a function keys (for example F3 and F6). We know that they are re-programmable and it can be used for different functions.
Thank you in advance!

I've already made them to work as a F3 and F6 thru keymap configuration, but after cold restar everything is lost permanently. Probably there is need of change in some configuration files.

Comment: How this is related to VBA?

Comment: I found something like Key Macro generator on VB, so I guess it could be some kind of helpful.